# Use webfont icon as placeholder in input field dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, webfonts

Im trying to dynamically set input field placeholder using MaterialDesignIcons webfont as placeholder font.

When used as **static** placeholder it works as expected and the icon is shown when text field is empty.

```
<input type="text" id="sampleInput" placeholder="&#xF6E3;" />

input#sampleInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: "Material Design Icons";
}
```

[image]

Using dynamic jquery method causes me some problems. It seems like character code is not escaped correctly to html.

```
$('#sampleInput').prop('placeholder',"&#xF6E3;");
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this :

```
$('#sampleInput').prop('placeholder',"\uxF6E3");
```

you can check this jsfiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/anaselalami/pty6ao7m/1/

Comment: Happy to be helpful :)